# CSS won't load on one page, but the same CSS will load perfectly with another page

Tags: html, css

As I mentioned, I have two pages, 403.html and 404.html , that require to load the same style.css file. When I reach the 403.html page, the CSS loads perfectly. When I reach the 404.html page, which has the SAME code except from some minor text changes, the CSS won't load and the page will be displayed as plain text. What I don't understand is that the path to the css is the same in both pages...
Is there an explanation ?

Structure of my folders : 
`|-errors
|     404.html
|     403.html
|--   css
|        style.css
|        style-mobile.css
|        etc...
|-site1
|-site2`

Addresses of pages : 79.143.188.169 will direct you to the 403 . 79.143.188.169/test will direct you to the 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error in `404` The links are:

```
/errors/js
```

And not:

```
/js
```

In your HTML, change:

```
<script src="js/skel.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/init.js"></script>
```

To:

```
<script src="errors/js/skel.min.js"></script>
<script src="errors/js/init.js"></script>
```

Changing the code fixes these issues!

Comment: I changed the code as you mentioned. It didn't fix the problem though. I'm actally browsing through the JS scripts to fix the paths. Do the paths have to be absolute or relative in JS ?

Comment: Okay, then give absolute path like this: `/errors/js/skel.min.js` and `/errors/js/init.js` and let me know. Check console for Error 404s...

Comment: I found the solution. I changed the paths in the init.js, which were wrong. Now the page loads fine. Thanks for having helped me to resolve this issue :D